# Unable to create react native app for version 0.6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I have react-native v0.63 and node v14.15.5 installed in my system. Now I want to make a project of react-native v0.6 instead. I have tried to create to create the project using two different commands. I have created the project using `rninit init [Project Name] --source react-native@0.6` and this `react-native init --version="react-native@0.6" Demoo`. At first I ran the command  `rninit init [Project Name] --source react-native@0.6` and I was able to create the project then I decided to run `npm install -g rninit` and then `rninit init [Project Name] --source react-native@0.6` after it. Now I unable to create the project using this command. . Also the created project using both of these commands doesn't contain essential files only the files in the  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NJxI.png) . Anyone knows how I can create and run the react-native v0.6 project?

Comment: Just do `npx create-react-app your-app-name` and then edit your package.json for changing the versions you need.